# When do I need to use docker ipvlan l3 network driver?

Tags: docker, docker-network

Provide real-world example, when I'll need to use ipvlan l3 type of network driver in Docker in two scenarios:

1. local development of simple reactjs/nodejs app.
2. local development and future producion of microservice app.

What are its key benifits compared to user defined bridge network driver in those scenarios?

I understand how this type of network works, but I can't imagine real-world situations when you technically need it, when you can't use any other driver.

Comment: What class? It's result of errors of stackoverflow form. It lives its own life. Fixed already. P.S. Something new, the question entry form makes adjustments itself. New AI?

Comment: The question is not associated with any professor or school. I started to deepen my knowledge of Docker, but I haven't found an answer to the question. Everything is very beautiful and attractive regarding the described driver, but for what cases in life is it needed when its relative complexity of setting is justified?

Comment: ahh okay hope you get an answer on this

Comment: I've never needed this setup FWIW, _especially_ in a development environment.  For almost-but-not-quite every case I've worked on, the default Docker networking setup has worked fine.

Comment: I've always used user defined bridge network and it has worked for me fine too. But now I have discovered new types of networks, and the question arose: “Perhaps I need this, but I don’t know it yet, or I don’t need it and won’t find it useful.” )

Comment: Oh great, someone voted to close this question because believes that the question is not about programming or software development. I agree, question about food, wrong section. ;)